# handling worldwide sites, multiple domains, seo

Tags: .htaccess, seo, dns

The company I work for has roughly 20 offices worldwide. We a domain for each office (all below, company name replaced with 'company'), each of which has its **own** unique website hosted for, in translated languages. As you could imagine, this makes things difficult for marketing purposes and for SEO purposes.

We are doing an overhaul of the website and would like to fix this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions as to implementation of these worldwide sites. We are thinking of doing IP detection and using the one **company.com** domain as the domain for marketing worldwide. Should we be marketing all 20 of these domains and redirecting them to company.com?

**Or** should we add a rewrite rule to *each* domain like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^companyworldwidesite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.companyworldwidesite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/company\.com\/$1" [P,L]
```

What is the best practice for handling worldwide sites, domains, seo, etc?

**Domains**

```
company.com
companycanada.com
companylatinamerica.com
companyuk.com
companyeurope.fr
company.se
companyeurope.de
companyeurope.pl
companycz.com
companyturkiye.com
companyaust.com
company.co.nz
companysingapore.com
companythailand.com
companyindonesia.com
company.com.tw
companybeijing.com
company.in
companymalaysia.com
companyafrica.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google recently explained how to handle situations like this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). Their example shows the usage of subdomains but you can use domains as well:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.company.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://company.es/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-MX" href="http://companymx.es/" />
```